# can I use PUT instead of POST for uploading using fineuploader?

Tags: fine-uploader

Is there a way to configure Fine uploader to use PUT request instead of POST request?  My company only supports PUT request for file uploading.  Thanks.

Comment: Uploads via PUT (where supported) will be allowed in Fine Uploader 5.2.  https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/734

Answer (score 1):

> Uploads via PUT are possible since Fine Uploader 5.2. See https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/734 for details.

<strike>This has been requested before. We have not implemented this due to the fact that this is not possible in all browsers. In IE9 and earlier, a form is constructed and submitted in order to upload the submitted file. Unfortunately, PUT is not a valid value for a form's method attribute. So, sending files via PUT requests would not be possible in all IE browsers other than IE10.</strike>

Also, this would not apply to Fine Uploader S3 and Fine Uploader Azure.  However, there is an open case requesting we allow this in modern browsers for uploads to traditional/custom end points.  See [issue 734 in the project's Github repo](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/734) for more info and updates.

Comment: Thanks Ray.  I was able to upload but the file name is changed.  Is there a way that I keep the original file name?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, see [the `blobProperties.name` option](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options-azure.html#blobProperties.name).

Comment: I try to set the name but it doesn't work.  I am not using Azure but S3.  Thanks.

Comment: Please show your code that attempts to use this function.

Comment: I am able to set the file name now using objectProperties.  Thanks a lot Ray.

Comment: I can't upload file to bucket with folder.  Is there anything special that I need to watch out for?  Thank you.