# Force S3 multipart uploads

Tags: fine-uploader

This is a follow-up to knt's question about PUT vs POST, with more details. The answer may be independently more useful to future answer-seekers.
[can I use PUT instead of POST for uploading using fineuploader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24729626/can-i-use-put-instead-of-post-for-uploading-using-fineuploader)

We have a mostly S3-compatible back-end that supports multipart upload, but not form POST, specifically policy signing. I see in the v5 migration notes that "even if chunking is enabled, a chunked upload request is only sent to traditional endpoints if the associated file must be broken into more than 1 chunk". How is the threshold determined for whether a file needs to be chunked? How can the threshold be adjusted? (or ideally, set to zero)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Fine Uploader will chunk a file if its size is less than the number of bytes specified in the [`chunking.partSize`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#chunking.partSize) option (default value is: `2000000` bytes). If your file is smaller than the size specified in that value, then it will not be chunked.

To effectively set it to "zero", you could just increase the `partSize` to an extremely large value. I also did some experimenting, and it seems like a `partSize` of -1 will make Fine Uploader NOT chunk files at all. AFAIK, that is not supported behavior, and I have not looked at *why* that is even possible.

Note that S3 requires chunks to be a *minimum* of 5MB.
Also, note that you may run into limitations on request size as imposed by certain browsers if you make `partSize` extremely large.